# How to ping rethinkdb in python,to check whether db server ain't down?

Tags: python, rethinkdb

```
import rethinkdb as r

con=r.connect(host='localhost')
```

How do I ping? How do I used existing connection to ping DB server?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that the connection is still healthy and running queries, you could do something like `r.expr(0).run(conn) == 0`.